# Is there a convention where to save common definitions

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I am creating a C# program (This question is general for any OOP language) which includes several logic parts, each is meant to deal with some service the program requires. For example, a database handler which is responsible for getting results from the database, a web service handler which is responsible for getting results from the web service etc...

Let's say the db has a table which contains a column with some enum values. The program can read these values which of course will be in the form of the enum. So this enum was specifically created for the db use, but is readable for several parts.

Where should this enum be defined in the OOP program side:

1) Should there be a general definition file which contains all definitions of common classes, types, enums etc.

2) Should there be several definitions files, one for each part? so the enum in this case will be defined in the db's definition file.

3) something else completely?

Comment: Regardless of where it is, an `enum` will always have a definition in your code, or else it doesn't exist. If the enum values are clearly named that provides some definition, and you can also add XML comments to both the `enum` and its values. I'd be cautious about defining something in more than one place because then they have to stay in sync. I'll always lean toward defining things in code because it's where the "brains" are and you can always view history to see what's changed and change something back. Anyone can change anything in a table.

Comment: This will depend on the size of the project. If I'm writing three small classes for a quickie, they may all go in one file. But on a serious project, each class/enum/whatever gets its own file, and I'll further organize with namespaces: The database stuff might all go in a Database namespace, for example. Web service stuff would go in another namespace. In VS, if you create a folder called `Database`, any class you create in there will automatically go in the namespace `MyProject.Database`.

Answer (score 2):

I create a utilities class for each project within the solution. It contains all methods that I commonly use like resetControls() which just iterates through a form and sets default values. I've found it to be a nice way to organize these by just calling them through utilities.method();

The other very commonly used method I have is utilities.Sanitize(string a) which I call on anything that needs to be cleaned before going anywhere near my database.

Comment: On a larger scale, the application I spend most of my time on has a Utilities project, containing many classes.